# DBT macro ignores leading if block

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I defined a macro that starts with:

```
{% macro my_macro(table, first=false) %}

{%- if first -%} WITH
{%- else -%} ,
{% endif %}

tmp AS (...
```

In the compiled SQL I see this is completely ignored. If I paste this exact same block after the first CTE, it inserts fine. If I put any text before the if-block, it will also render the text + content of if-block.

I don't understand this behaviour. How can I make this macro work leading either with WITH or ","?

Even if I replace `first` with `true` it doesn't show up.

Additional information:
I'm working with BigQuery and dbt version 0.18.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error I realised that using "-" to reduce white space on the first line somehow removes the text coming after it as well.
So

```
{%- if first -%}
WITH
...
```

Doesn't work, but

```
{% if first %}
WITH
...
```

is fine. It was a simple fix, but I doubt this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

interesting problem! A couple of questions:

1. What database are you working with?
2. What version of dbt are you working with?
3. Where does `first` come from in your query?

On Azure Synapse and with dbt version 0.18.1, I was able to successfully use the following:

```sql
{% set first = true %}

{%- if first -%}
WITH 
{%- else -%} , 
{% endif %}

top_100 AS (

    SELECT 100 AS MyNumber


),

top_10 AS (

    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM top_100

)

SELECT * FROM top_10
```

Comment: I added the answers to the question. Thanks David!

Comment: I found the cause (see other answer), but don't know why it happens

Comment: Oh wow, that's so strange! If you can reproduce that more generally, I'd imagine it would be a good issue to raise.